# Перегрузка операции умножения для двух списков C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, перегрузка-операторов

Как "перегрузить" операцию умножение так, чтобы можно было умножать список на список и результат записывать в новый список? 
Т.е. `A` - список целых чисел, `B` - список целых чисел и `C` - список целых чисел
и должно получится что-то вроде этого `C = A * B`

Comment: Каким образом вы собираетесь перемножать списки разного размера?

Comment: можете посмотреть как реализован этот оператор для std::valarray

Comment: Если Вас интересует умножение элементов списка "в столбик", то используйте [длинную арифметику].
[длинную арифметику]: https://e-maxx.ru/algo/big_integer

Answer (score 1):

То, что вы хотите сделать, умеет [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), если применять [std::multiplies](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/multiplies)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::list<int> lst1{1,2,3,4,5};
    std::list<int> lst2{6,7,8,9,10};
    std::list<int> lstOut;


    std::transform(lst1.begin(), lst1.end(),
                   lst2.begin(),
                   std::back_inserter(lstOut),
                   std::multiplies<int>());
    for (auto const & el : lstOut)
        std::cout << el << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Результат

```
6 14 24 36 50
```

Comment: нужно чтобы перемножался каждый элемент из первого списка на каждый элемент второго.